# problem with using mojang leveldb library

Tags: c++, leveldb

I am trying to use mojang leveldb from github page but I dont know how. When I include the include file I get DLLX incomplete type and other problems. So, how to use this library. I am on Windows 10 and visual studio 2019

Comment: You say _"mojang"_ but leveldb is a Goolge project from here - https://github.com/google/leveldb , which project should we look at ? And did it build successfully ?

Comment: There is a mcpe versionn which is a modification of google leveldb.

Comment: Search mcpe-leveldb you should find it

Comment: Here is the link: https://github.com/Mojang/leveldb-mcpe

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Ok my problem is that I have no experience with leveldb. I am trying to extract minecraft level information using their version of leveldb but i cant get it to work. The problem is that when I include files from leveldb I get compilation errors.So do any one knows how to correctly set it up

Comment: my problem is that i want to use this library but dont know how to include it